How to Replace an LMMSE Equalizer with a Conjugate Gradient Method in MIMO Detection?
I'm currently working on a MIMO detection problem, and I need to replace the LMMSE equalizer with a Conjugate Gradient (CG) method.

Now, I want to replace this LMMSE equalizer with a Conjugate Gradient method. I'm looking for a CG implementation that will achieve the same goal, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I understand that CG is often used to solve systems of linear equations, so it seems like a good fit for this problem.
Can anyone provide guidance or code examples on how to implement the Conjugate Gradient method for this MIMO detection problem?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
